# An error in Alpyne library in a RL problem

Tags: python, simulation, reinforcement-learning, anylogic, stock

I am new to RL and wanted to test some examples about it.
One of the examples is stock management problem and I wanted to run "rlpolicy_train.py" on google Colab.
The link for example:

https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/Alpyne/tree/main/examples/Stock%20Management%20Game

It seems that there is an error in Alpyne Library and I can't understand what is the meaning of this error and how I can fix it.
The screenshot of the error has been attached.
[image]
I would appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: You best reach out to Tyler Wolfe-Adam, the creator of the library :)